# Creating multi-dimensional array of hashes

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, multidimensional-array

I want to loop through a multi-dimensional array:

```
array = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
```

and create a hash with keys from a another array:

```
keyValues = "one","two","three","four","five"
```

I have the following code to do this:

```
hash = Hash.new
multiArray = Array.new
array.each do |values|
  keyValues.each do |key|
    i = keyValues.index(key)
    hash[key] = values[i]
  end
  puts hash
  multiArray << hash     
end
puts multiArray
```

The `puts hash` outputs:

```
{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5}
{"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}
```

and the final `multiArray` is:

```
{"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}
{"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}
```

I can't figure out why I'm not getting:

```
{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5}
```

for the final `multiArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has two entries of the same hash object. So if you change the hash object anywhere, it will change in both array entries. To avoid having the same exact hash object in each array entry, you can duplicate the hash before inserting, by changing `multiArray << hash` to `multiArray << hash.dup`

Answer (score 3):

Now that @August has identified the problem with your code, I'd like to suggest a compact, Ruby-like way to obtain the result you want.

**Code**

```
def make_hash(array, key_values)
    array.map { |a| key_values.zip(a).to_h }
end
```

**Example**

```
array = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]] 
key_values = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

make_hash(array, key_values)
  #=> [{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5},
  #    {"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}]
```

**Explanation**

The first value passed into the block by [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

so we have

```
b = key_values.zip(a)
  #=> [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3], ["four", 4], ["five", 5]]
b.to_h
  #=> {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5}
```

For Ruby versions < 2.0 (when [Array.to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was introduced), we'd have to write `Hash(b)` rather than `b.to_h`.

Similarly, the second value passed to the block is:

```
a = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

so

```
key_values.zip(a).to_h
  #=> {"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install `y_support` gem (`gem install y_support`). It defines `Array#>>` operator useful for constructing hashes:

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/array'
[ :a, :b, :c ] >> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

With it, your job can be done like this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10] 
key_values = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

multi_array = array.map { |a| key_values >> a }
#=> [{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5},
     {"one"=>6, "two"=>7, "three"=>8, "four"=>9, "five"=>10}]
```